# evaluating a ruby expression

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

`<% if (true || date[4..7].to_i > 1105) && most_recent_dis_table.present? %>`

I found this piece of code. I understand this expression as the part before '&&' always evaluates to true. the second part checks for the presence of most_recent_dis_table.

Is my interpretation correct? I guess I don't understand why the first part exists if it always evaluates as true.

Comment: Sometimes people jam in things like `true` or `false` to force a particular evaluation path when debugging. Sometimes people forget to remove these before pushing.

Answer (score 2):

Your interpretation is correct. There is no point in having `(true || date[4..7].to_i > 1105) &&` in that condition since the left side of the OR will always make the entire OR expression `true`.

The developer who wrote it probably left `true ||` in the code accidentally.